# How to update an ASP.NET page? Like in a Forum or a Chat?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a created a Forum and I want the page to update if another user responds to a question, much like a chat page where it updates in real-time. How or what method should be done for the page to refresh (I used ListView for the replies and bind it using objectdatasource)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SignalR, it will help you to send messages from the backend to the browser when another user posted a message.

You should also use SignalR groups to group users by a forum topic in order to send to those users that exist in a specific group

Read more about [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) here

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET SignalR libray could be you're looking for.

Check this [link](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr) for more information and examples.